# Export Display to two vnc clients

Tags: linux, vnc

I am trying to display my vnc server on two vnc clients but can't seem to figure how to export display simultaneously to two vnc clients.

Can I use the export command to export display to two clients? Something like

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY=:1.0
```

Comment: I don't thin this has anything to do with exporting displays - isn't it just a matter of configuring the VNC server's `-shared` option?

Comment: How can I do that in tigerVNC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it with export.It will always set the Display to the latest value ie 2.0 as per the example you gave.